# Misusing Random Forest?

Tags: random-forest

I'm trying to wrap my mind around some analysis someone just showed me that someone said will be published soon. These people have about 60 cases and are interested in a disease that occurs in 5 of these cases. They do a random forest algorithm and then do the variable importance of the random forest using a variable importance command in R. They use the output of the variable importance command to select variables to perform sensitivity analysis on to see what variables "accurately predict" the disease. There's no mention of the accuracy of the random forest at predicting this disease, but I'm guessing it's probably terrible at predicting the disease with so few cases. In that case is this analysis just pointless?

To add: these people seem to think random forest is somehow really accurate with small data. Don't know about that, but they've never tested the accuracy

Comment: Agree. Random forests should not be tried on such small data.

Comment: Do you understand whats up with the variable importance thing? I really don't get how this is a valuable metric when the random forest is probably classifying nothing correctly

Comment: Irrespective of the accuracy of RF, variable importance estimates are consistent and informative measures of potential usefulness of the features. As long as there is enough data, not 60 observations.

Comment: Under what conditions could the variable importance estimates change? If I add more data? I'm surprised the "important" variables would be informative if the underlying decision trees aren't able to accurately classify the disease. Wouldn't that be like saying I can run random forest on any dataset and whatever variables come out as important are good?

Comment: I gave you the answer. To understand the variable importance measures, you can refer to _"Hastie, T., Tibshirani, R., & Friedman, J. H. (2008). The elements of statistical learning: Data mining, inference, and prediction. New York: Springer."_

Comment: hmm I read the section on variable importance, but I didn't see anything like this